MAX3098 IC Circuit
I am reading the data from the encoder speed sensor. OUT statements represent the data coming from my sensor. The integrated one shown in the picture does not function as MUX, but is referred to as MUX on the internet. When I look at the datasheet, I see that there is an integration specifically for the encoder. What is the circuit and integrated function in the image? How does it work?

It might be a good idea to explain what you mean by "integrate one", and provide a link to the datasheet. Edit the details into your question - not in the comments.

ozak - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each copied / adapted item. If the original source is online & public, please [edit] the question & add the webpage/PDF name & its link (URL) (e.g. website name + webpage title + its URL). If the source is offline (e.g. book or private intranet) then [edit] the question & add full source details e.g. title, author, page, publisher, edition. TY (More site rules in the [tour] & [help])

Similar comment to what @SamGibson wrote.  You wrote "...is referred to as MUX on the internet."  Add a link to the page where you read it, so that we can read it too.

The purpose of the MAX3098E is to convert a differential digital signal to single-ended.  RS-485 and RS-422 are differential digital signal standard.  MAX3098E is an RS-485 receiver.
MAX3098E has three channels (A, B, Z). That's intended for motor encoders, because incremental quadrature encoders often have 3 channels.  (See fig.7 in the datasheet.)  Channel Z isn't used in your circuit.
Also notice that MAX3098E can only receive.  It doesn't have a capability to transmit RS-485.  For a comparison, a typical RS-485 transceiver has 2 channels: one for receiving, and one for transmitting.
It's not uncommon for motor encoders to output differential signals, because differential signal are more immune to interference.  Large motors can generate a lot of interference in the vicinity, and shaft encoders are located close to motors.

The integrated one [integrated circuit MAX3098E] shown in the picture does not function as MUX, but is referred to as MUX on the internet.

The datasheet of the source of truth.  "MUX [short for multiplexer]" isn't mentioned anywhere in the datasheet.  This IC receives and outputs all three channels at the same time.  It doesn't multiplex.
